# Message box under the main window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi

Sometimes my message box is shown *under* the main window of the application. Thus, message box is invisible and the main window looks like it's hanged and doesn't responds to any input. It's possible to "unfreeze" the main window by using alt-tab to switch to another app and back, and it finally shows message box in it's right place - above the main window. But this is not obvious for the user.

Any ideas, how to avoid this problem?

UPD the main window is native; I've tried using MessageBox with and without specifying parent window, but had the same problem in both cases

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what was the reason, but using my own wrapper for the native parent window fixed this problem:

```
public class Win32Window : IWin32Window
{
    public Win32Window(IntPtr val)
    {
        _handle = val;
    }

    readonly IntPtr _handle;

    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get { return _handle; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually when you call message box functions, they take a "parent" window as an argument.  Which window are you passing as the "parent" window?

Comment: Request handle in the host app and use Control.FromHandle() to wrap

Comment: @user: Then chances are, the host app is passing NULL (`IntPtr.Zero`), which causes the message box to display with the desktop window as its parent. That's going to put it underneath your application's window. Show the rest of the code to get better help.

Comment: @Cody Gray, it's not zero. And if desktop window was it's parent, it wouldn't freeze the main window of my app.

Comment: @user: Your question mentions using a messagebox "without specifying a parent window". It would be null in that case. Another possibility is that you're passing a handle for a window that is below your main window. It's really impossible to say without seeing some code. I'm not sitting close enough to your monitor to read it from here.

Comment: @Cody Gray, this is not correct. When no owner window is specified, .NET detects the active window. The "main window" means, ughm, that it's main and is the ultimate parent of every other window in my app. There can't be window below it, inside the same process.

Answer (score 0):

may be you call message box in a second thread not in main thread